# clearing persistent variables in code generation matlab

Tags: matlab, code-generation

I need to clear persistent variables in my code, but during code generation in matlab it says:

> Function `clear` is not supported for code generation and the coder.extrinsic directive cannot be applied to `clear`. Rewrite your code so it does not use `clear`.

I did what a normal person would do and assigned the persistent variable to an empty array, but it also complains with:

> Assigning empty arrays to persistent variables is not supported.

Does anyone know any way around this? how can I clear persistent variables in code generation?

Comment: Why do you want to clear the persistent variables? There may be alternate ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: I can probably avoid using persistent variables altogether, but I wanted to avoid code rewrite. I use persistent variables for plot handles so that I can only change ydata and it is therefore faster and then I can achieve an animation effect. Each time I start an animation sequence I clear everything, so it was easier

Comment: @user27221 There are a lot of ways to store plot handles. If you post some code we can help you adapt it to avoid the persistent variables.

Comment: thanks, but cleaning up the code to show more details than what I just said is perhaps more work than finding the workaround myself. If there is no way of doing this, I think the question should remain unanswered, right?

Comment: You are likely using some extrinsic function to create these persistent variables. May be you can move these persistent variables to those extrinsic functions.